# Extracting the value by xpath in python between tags

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I want to extract parameter that I referred in the picture below...

What I have tried is:

```
url='http://site.ir'
content=requests.get(url).content
tree = html.fromstring(content)
print [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]/????')]
```

This is not in tag **span** and not in tag **br** .

The picture:
[image]

## UPDATE

imagine I have:

```
out=""" <div class="groupinfo">
    <div class="grouptext">
        <span style="color:#5f0101">
            span tag contents
        </span>
        WHAT I WANT
        <br></br>
    </div>
</div> <div class="groupinfo">
    <div class="grouptext">
        <span style="color:#5f0101">
            span tag contents
        </span>
        WHAT I WANT(1)
        <br></br>
    </div>
</div> 
imagine I have: out=""" <div class="groupinfo">
    <div class="grouptext">
        <span style="color:#5f0101">
            span tag contents
        </span>
        WHAT I WANT(2)
        <br></br>
    </div>
</div> <div class="groupinfo">
    <div class="grouptext">
        <span style="color:#5f0101">
            span tag contents
        </span>
        WHAT I WANT(3)
        <br></br>
    </div>
</div> """"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to get the **following** to `span` text **sibling**:

```
//div[@class="grouptext"]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()
```

Demo:

```
from lxml import html

data = """
<div class="groupinfo">
    <div class="grouptext">
        <span style="color:#5f0101">
            span tag contents
        </span>
        WHAT I WANT
        <br></br>
    </div>
</div>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(data)
print tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()')[0].strip()
```

Prints:

```
WHAT I WANT
```

---

For the updated example, here's what worked for me:

```
for result in tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]/span/following-sibling::text()'):
    print result.strip()
```

Prints:

```
WHAT I WANT

WHAT I WANT(1)

WHAT I WANT(2)

WHAT I WANT(3)
```

Comment: Good, Thank you... If in this page I have for example 20 of these structure... How can I extract all of them???

Comment: I mean I want: `text()')[0].strip() --- text()')[3].strip() ---- text()')[6].strip() ---- text()')[9].strip() .... etc`

Comment: @MortezaLSC as far as I understood, omit the `[1]` next to span - let it check every `span` inside the `div`. If this is not what you mean, please provide the related HTML code so that I can play around with it and provide you a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you I accepted your answer... I think this is out of xpath structure...yes?

Comment: Your solution doen;t work but as I said [0]...[3]...[6]......[87] is extracting for me all parameters....

Comment: @MortezaLSC Ok, thanks, I will take a look later today.

Comment: I got the main answer by adding:`    while count<=87:
        print tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()')[count].strip()
        count = count + 3`

Comment: @MortezaLSC ok, then just FYI, I've updated the answer with the solution for the updated example you provided. Check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's the text content of a `div` element. Unfortunately, "what you want" is unreadable because you scribbled "WHAT I WANT" on it.

What you are (most likely) looking for is a text node, that is not actually "between tags", it is a child of the `div[@class="grouptext"]`element. There might be more than one such text node as a child of this div.

Try:

```
print [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]')]
```

Or

```
print tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]/text()')
```

might work as well, but I am not quite familiar with Python.

Comment: You mean there is no way to extract parameter I referred?

Comment: Can I say: Extract everything after span and before br?

Comment: @MortezaLSC I am not sure you understand that the problem is that you do **not** show exactly the part of the HTML that we need to look at. Please post real code, not one in an image and without the crucial part scribbled on. Also, show the whole content of that div, not only the beginning.